# How to write only selected class fields into CSV with CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I use [`CsvHelper`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) to read and write CSV files and it is great, yet I don't understand how to write only selected type fields.

Say we had:

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

namespace Project
{
    public class DataView
    {
        [CsvField(Name = "N")]
        public string ElementId { get; private set; }

        [CsvField(Name = "Quantity")]
        public double ResultQuantity { get; private set; }

        public DataView(string id, double result)
        {
            ElementId = id;
            ResultQuantity = result;
        }
    }
}
```

and we wanted to exclude "Quantity" `CsvField` from resulting CSV file that we currently generate via something like:

```
using (var myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
{
    using (var writer = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(myStream)))
    {
        writer.Configuration.Delimiter = '\t';
        writer.WriteHeader(typeof(ResultView));
        _researchResults.ForEach(writer.WriteRecord);
    }
}
```

What could I use to dynamically exclude a type field from the CSV?

If it is necessary we could process the resulting file, yet I do not know how to remove an entire CSV column with `CsvHelper`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
using (var myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
{
    using (var writer = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(myStream)))
    {
        writer.Configuration.AttributeMapping(typeof(DataView)); // Creates the CSV property mapping
        writer.Configuration.Properties.RemoveAt(1); // Removes the property at the position 1
        writer.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";
        writer.WriteHeader(typeof(DataView));
        _researchResults.ForEach(writer.WriteRecord);
    }
}
```

We are forcing the creation of the attribute mapping and then modifying it, removing the column dynamically.

Comment: Is this for an old version of CsvHelper?  `AttributeMapping` and `Properties` doesn't exist when I drill down into `writer.configuration`?

Answer (score 21):

I recently needed to achieve a similar result by determining what fields to include at runtime.  This was my approach:

1. Create a mapping file to map which fields I need at runtime by passing in an enum into the class constructor

   ```
   public sealed class MyClassMap : CsvClassMap<MyClass>
   {
       public MyClassMap(ClassType type)
       {
           switch (type)
           {
               case ClassType.TypeOdd
                   Map(m => m.Field1);
                   Map(m => m.Field3);
                   Map(m => m.Field5);                 
                   break;
               case ClassType.TypeEven:
                   Map(m => m.Field2);
                   Map(m => m.Field4);
                   Map(m => m.Field6);                 
                   break;
               case ClassType.TypeAll:
                   Map(m => m.Field1);
                   Map(m => m.Field2);
                   Map(m => m.Field3);
                   Map(m => m.Field4);
                   Map(m => m.Field5);
                   Map(m => m.Field6);                 
                   break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Write out the records to using the mapping configuration

   ```
   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
   using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
   {
       csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new MyClassMap(ClassType.TypeOdd));
       csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
       streamWriter.Flush();
       return memoryStream.ToArray();
   }
   ```

Comment: This is the correct way to do on latest (as of Dec 2015).

Answer (score 9):

Mark the field like this:

```
[CsvField( Ignore = true )]
public double ResultQuantity { get; private set; }
```

**Update:** Nevermind. I see you want to do this at runtime, rather than compile time. I'll leave this up as red flag for anyone else who might make the same mistake.

Comment: And, `CsvFieldAttribute` was removed in version 2.0.

Comment: Was it replaced with anything?

Comment: they replace with `[Ignore]`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with my code and I fixed it by the following code.

you can do this:

```
var ignoreQuantity = true;
using (var myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
{
    using (var writer = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(myStream)))
    {
        var classMap = new DefaultClassMap<DataView>();
        classMap.AutoMap();
        classMap.Map(m => m.ResultQuantity).Ignore(ignoreQuantity)

        writer.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(classMap);

        writer.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";
        writer.WriteHeader(typeof(DataView));
        _researchResults.ForEach(writer.WriteRecord);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. Just want to point out that if `DataView` class has sub-classes, each property in it should also be set to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

I had to solve this also: I have a couple dozen record types with a common base class plus a common field that has to be ignored by all of them:

```
// Nothing special here
internal class MyClassMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : MyRecordBaseClass
{ 
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        Map( m => m.SOME_FIELD ).Ignore();
    }
}
```

This part is generally well documented and not the dynamic part.

But *one* class needed special sauce by ignoring a different field dynamically, and though I could have created a separate map class, this didn't scale for what I expect will be a lot more of these, so I finally figured out how to do it properly:

```
    ...
    // special processing for *one* record type
    csvwriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyClassMap<ONE_RECORD_TYPE>>();

    if (ShouldIgnore)
    {
        var map = csvwriter.Configuration.Maps.Find<ONE_RECORD_TYPE>();
        map.Map( m => m.SOME_OTHER_FIELD ).Ignore();
    }
    ...
```

This worked on CsvHelper versions 7.1.1 and 12.1.1.

Comment: This was extremely close to what I was trying to achieve, it helped a lot, cheers.